# Restoring modprobe configurations

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

While trying to fix clickpad issues, I seem to have messed up my psmouse.conf. I attempted to follow the instructions here:

[Right mouse button doesnt work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191864/right-mouse-button-doesnt-work)

As mentioned by the answer on that post, the right-side detection was fixed, but full touchpad detection was broken and a number of more important features were broken such as scrolling. How can I restore /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf to how it was on install, along with any additional files effected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed the instructions **faithfully**, just run:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf
```

Then run

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse
```

You will be left without the right button, though (as you were before you made modifications).